# Python 2.7: double backslash comparison

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, compare, backslash

I'm trying to know if I have a string with two backslash or more. My problem is that after some string treatment, I have my string to check like:

- `'\string'` when it has only one backslash charater (it should be `'\\string'` insteed).
- `'\\string'` when it has two bakslashes (it should be `'\\\\string'`).

Is there any way to check the number of backslashes the string have? As `'\string' == '\\string'` is `True`.

Comment: There is **no double backslash** in your string. There is just one backslash, but to make the value *reproducable*, Python shows an *escaped* backslash in the produced Python string literal.

Comment: Only when you use `r'\\s'` is there actually a double backslash in the value. At that point, `r'\\' in r'\\s'` is indeed true, but don't confuse an escaped backslash for two backslash characters.

Comment: Raw string literals is just a *syntax*, a different way to spell the same value. `r'\\s'` is the same value as `'\\\\s'`, using different syntax. There is no 'raw string type', you can't turn a Unicode value into a raw string value, because there is no such thing.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question to explain in a better way my problem. Thanks.

Comment: For your new question: no, your string still has only one backslash. At no point do you have strings with two backslashes, because **to Python** there is no difference between `'\s'` and `'\\s'` in a string literal.

Comment: Ok thaks for your anwser. Really the are a string with two backslashes, you can see the behaivour I explain in the question by executing `exec "foo('{0}')".format('\\s')` and `exec "foo('{0}')".format('\\\\s')` where **foo** function just print the parameter that recives. By doing that you get the same result, because it is like you give `'\s'` and `'\\s'` to the function.
Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You are *still* just passing `'\\s'` and `'\s'` literals to a function there.

Comment: You'd get something else if you used `foo({0!r})` instead, asking Python to interpolate the representation of the string, not the string value.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know that format specification, it may help me in the future. Bad new is that I cannot change the way the function is called, I just can change the function so no solution until I could change how its called. Should I make any change in the question? I mean edit it to show there is no anwser or something (I don't kwon how  I should proceed with it). Thank you again.

Comment: Are you saying you have a function that uses `eval()` to pass in strings? That's... broken code.

Comment: Yeah... that's "old code" (wrote before I start working) I have to deal with. I hope I could change it in a near future.